# How to generate an editable diagram from SQL file?

Tags: erd, diagramming, graphml

I have SQL files with DDL statements (create table, create view, ...). I want to generate ERD from them that I can further refine in a diagram editor (Dia, yEd, Visio or the like). Tools that I found are usually working with a connection to a running database and/or output diagrams in poorly-editable formats (like JPG).

Is there any tool that can generate ER diagram in reasonably editable format, like *.gml, *.graphml or *.gxl?

(My specific case is for PostgreSQL, but I can probably transform that into other dialect with SwisSQL if needed. A tool that can work with multiple dialects would be, of course, the best.)